# UIPageControl in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageViewController`, but I want to make the `UIPageControl` have the same colour as the background I set in the child view controller. How would I do this? I tried setting `UIPageControl.appearance()` in `AppDelegate`, but that didn't do anything.
Important to know: I want to make the `UIPageControl` have the same colour as the child view controller it is on, this varies, so how do I do this?

[image: Example from simulator]

Comment: Add some code so some one here can help you

Comment: I feel like I included everything necessary, what kind of code would you need?

Comment: Try putting `UIPageControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue` in `viewDidLoad` of your `UIPageViewController` class. Worked fine for me (obviously, change `.blue` to your color...).

Comment: Actually, I just tried it in `AppDelegate` and it also worked fine. Check your syntax?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as I noted in a comment under the first answer: it seems that the `UIPageControl` in a `UIPageViewController` can't really be customized?

Comment: @jbehrens94 - if it "doesn't work for you" there must be something else going on. I just tested it, without problem. I can set the appearance for `.backgroundColor` `.pageIndicatorTintColor` and `.currentPageIndicatorTintColor`, all in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate.

Comment: Here's a screen-cap: https://imgur.com/5NfhGKX ... ugly color combination to make it obvious.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example on git? I mean, I could link you to my setup, but I don't think that would help you very much.

Comment: Sure, I'll get you a link in a minute....

Comment: OK - I took the default Page View template and made the bare-minimum of changes needed. I committed it first with NO changes, then committed with changes, so it'll be pretty easy to see: https://github.com/DonMag/BasicPageVC